# Attaching char buffer to vector<char> in STL

Tags: c++, stl, vector

What is the correct (and efficient) way of attaching the contents of C buffer (`char *`) to the end of `std::vector<char>`?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

When you have a `vector<char>` available, you're probably best calling the `vector<char>::insert` method:

```
std::vector<char> vec;

const char* values="values";
const char* end = values + strlen( values );

vec.insert( vec.end(), values, end );
```

Delegating it to the vector is to be preferred to using a `back_inserter` because the vector can then decide upon its final size.  The `back_inserter` will only `push_back`, possibly causing more reallocations.

Answer (score 7):

I think the proper way would be to

```
vec.insert(vec.end(),buf,buf+length);
```

or

```
std::copy(buf,buf+length,std::back_inserter(vec));
```

**Edit:** I reordered two examples, so it's not that commenters are wrong, it's just me ;-)

Comment: While the first is correct, too, the second it better, because the vector can deduce that the iterators are random-access iterators and use them to reserve beforehand, saving possible re-allocations.

Comment: True. I wouldn't expect that much from it, though. Anyway, there's more than one road to Rome ;-)

Comment: I'd actually expect the second to be better, because many modern implementations now optimize simple cases. This is simple in three ways: `vector<>` is a simple template, `char*` is a simple iterator, and `char` is a simple POD.

Comment: I'll reorder them on popular demand, but the main point I'm trying to make is that it's good to have more than one way. Thanks MSalters and sbi for your comments.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't compiled it, but it should be something like:

```
const char string1[] = "a string";
std::vector<char> vData;
vData.insert(vData.end(), string1, string1+strlen(string1));
```