# Copy multiple void* into one vector

Tags: c++, vector

I am coming back to C++ after many years (and never went so deeply before), so please indulge with me for my noobness :)

I have, as a field of a struct, a *void which points to some data. The memory pointed by the struct is filled with different data after every call of a given function, so I'd like to "cache" the results after every function call in a vector, in order to obtain all data in the end. How can I achieve this goal?

I declared a `static vector<unsigned char> vectorBuffer;` and tried `vectorBuffer.insert(vectorBuffer.end(), (unsigned char*)myStruct->thePointer)` and `vectorBuffer.push_back((unsigned char*)myStruct->thePointer)` but obviously I'm getting errors. Which is the correct way to obtain such a result?

Thanks

EDIT: I know the size of the void* as well, since I have another field in my struct that refreshes as the data do.

Comment: For starters you need to kow the length of the data.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/1399666/534005 - this is essentially what you want to do. I.e. buffer the data from the struct in a vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something along these lines is what you want to do to buffer the data fragmented over multiple callbacks:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<char> buffer;

buffer.insert(buffer.end(), data, data+length);
```

Assuming that `data` is your data coming in the callback and length is available too.

Comment: I got the point, but it still doesn't compile. On the third parameter i get an error: as soon as I try do add `myStruct->dataLength` to `myStruct->myData` i get "Error: expression must be a pointer to a complete object type". Which is kinda weird since, as said, `myStruct->dataLength` is a `void*` ...

Comment: Finally I got it working. The final solution was to use a vector as a temporary buffer every time the callback function is executed:

`vector<char> tempbuffer((unsigned char*)myStruct->myData, (unsigned char*)myStruct->myData + myStruct->dataLength);

vectorBuffer.insert(vectorBuffer.end(), tempbuffer.begin(), tempbuffer.end());`

However I'll accept your answer as it helped me a lot. Thanks you, and everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the vector with

```
static vector<unsigned char *> vectorBuffer;
```

(it's an array of unsigned character pointers, not unsigned characters).

To save the data (assuming you know the size),

```
unsigned char *p = new unsigned char[myStruct->bufferLength];
memcpy((void *) p, myStruct->thePointer, myStruct->bufferLength);
vectorBuffer.push_back(p);
```

You can then keep track of the length with

```
static vector<unsigned char *> bufferLength;
bufferLength.push_back(myStruct->bufferLength);
```

Note that you will need to free the memory afterwards.

Comment: He said the pointed data is changed after every function call, so collecting the same pointer doesn't make any sense

Comment: +1 @VladLazarenko: I need to copy actual data, not pointers. In my mind is something like a StringBuilder from Java (but of course it's just an example).

Comment: Do you know the size of the data (ie. as something like myStruct->theSize)?

Comment: @Lorthirk: You can't do much with it w/o knowing how many bytes are there to copy :)

Comment: As I said in the edit, I know how much data to copy every time since I have myStruct->bufferLength which gets refreshed as data does.

Comment: Edited the answer to fix the previous problems.